# pointer get wrong value in different thread

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

I am writing a piece of code to demonstrate the multi-threading share memory writing.

However, my code gets a strange 0xffffffff pointer I can't make out why. I haven't been writing cpp code for a while. please let me know if I get something wrong.

I compile with the command:
`g++ --std=c++11 shared_mem_multi_write.cpp  -lpthread  -g`

I get error echoes like:

```
function base_ptr: 0x5eebff, src_ptr: 0x7f21a9c4e010, size: 6220800
function base_ptr: 0xffffffffffffffff, src_ptr: 0x7f21a9c4e010, size: 6220800
function base_ptr: 0xbdd7ff, src_ptr: 0x7f21a9c4e010, size: 6220800
function base_ptr: 0x23987ff, src_ptr: 0x7f21a9c4e010, size: 6220800
function base_ptr: 0x11cc3ff, src_ptr: 0x7f21a9c4e010, size: 6220800
function base_ptr: 0x17bafff, src_ptr: 0x7f21a9c4e010, size: 6220800
function base_ptr: 0x1da9bff, src_ptr: 0x7f21a9c4e010, size: 6220800
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

my os is CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) gcc version 4.8.5 and the code is posted below:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

const size_t THREAD_CNT = 40;
const size_t FRAME_SIZE = 1920 * 1080 * 3;
const size_t SEG_SIZE = FRAME_SIZE * THREAD_CNT;

void func(char *base_ptr, char *src_ptr, size_t size)
{
    printf("function base_ptr: %p, src_ptr: %p, size: %u\n", base_ptr, src_ptr, size);
    while (1)
    {
        auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        memcpy(base_ptr, src_ptr, size);
        std::chrono::system_clock::time_point next_ts =
            now + std::chrono::milliseconds(42); // 24 frame per seconds => 42 ms per frame
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(next_ts);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int shmkey = 666;
    int shmid;
    shmid = shmget(shmkey, SEG_SIZE, IPC_CREAT);
    char *src_ptr = new char[FRAME_SIZE];
    char *shmpointer = static_cast<char *>(shmat(shmid, nullptr, 0));
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::thread>> t_vec;
    t_vec.reserve(THREAD_CNT);
    for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_CNT; ++i)
    {
        //t_vec[i] = std::thread(func, i * FRAME_SIZE + shmpointer, src_ptr, FRAME_SIZE);
        t_vec[i] = std::make_shared<std::thread>(func, i * FRAME_SIZE + shmpointer, src_ptr, FRAME_SIZE);
    }
    for (auto &&t : t_vec)
    {
        t->join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A call to `reserve` followed by arbitrary indexing doesn't seem like a good idea. Did you mean to `resize` the vector instead?

Comment: What's the reason of using such a construct like this: `std::shared_ptr<std::thread>`?

Comment: @You I have thought to keep the thread object in the vector. since the thread object has no default constructor function, I reserve here instead of creating a blank object.

Comment: Why do you use SHM at all? Heap space is shared by C++11 threads.

Comment: I am trying to do a demo, shm is for the demo. @DanielLangr

Comment: I just need to join the threads I create, so I want to keep the pointer or something I can get to the threads by. @vahancho

Comment: Since you use `reserve` instead of `resize`, the `for (auto &&t: t_vec)` loop works on an empty vector so none of your threads are joined.  When the destructor of a joinable thread is called, the program will `termiinate()`.

Comment: Running 40 threads simultaneously won't help much unless you're on a system with at least 20+ cores.

Comment: By the way, the correct `printf` format for a `size_t` is `"%zu"`.

Comment: And you don't need pointers to store `std::thread` in a vector. `std::thread` allow for move semantics.

Comment: in the first for loop I assign ever thread into the vector object, so I think it could fetch later. besides, my code is not failed on the join step. @1201ProgramAlarm

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude nice tips. I never heard of that, thank you

Comment: There's a very big difference between [`std::vector::reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) and [`std::vector::resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize). Because of that difference your program have *undefined behavior!*

Comment: I turn the "t_vec.reserve" into "t_vec.resize", but still get the same problem. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: I do understand the reserve call to the container of the pointer related object may cause UB and I've fixed that but still get the same error.... And I can't get any infomation useful even in the gdb debugger...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192932/discussion-between-liu-weibo-and-some-programmer-dude).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot specify access rights for created SHM segment (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html):

> The value shmflg is composed of:
>
> ...
>
> In addition to the above flags, **the least significant 9 bits of shmflg specify the permissions granted to the owner, group, and others**. These bits have the same format, and the same meaning, as the mode argument of open(2). Presently, execute permissions are not used by the system.

Change

```
shmid = shmget(shmkey, SEG_SIZE, IPC_CREAT);
```

into

```
shmid = shmget(shmkey, SEG_SIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
```

It works for me now: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Am4r2GBvM7kSmpdO

---

Note that I use only a vector of threads (no shared pointers), as other suggested in comments. You can possibly `reserve` its space as well.

Comment: exactly!! key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status
0x01136b8c 1245184    root       600        1000       7
0x0000029a 1277953    lwb   0          248832000  0 My bad, forget to set the permission!.

Comment: @LiuWeibo Don't also forget to remove undefined behavior from your original code.

Answer (score 2):

You forget one *very* important thing: Error handling!

Both the [`shmget`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shmget.html) and [`shmat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shmat.html) functions can fail. If they fail they return the value `-1`.

Now if you look at the first `base_ptr` value, it's `0x5eebff`. That just happens to be the same as `FRAME_SIZE - 1` (`FRAME_SIZE` is `0x5eec00`). That means `shmat` *do* return `-1`, and has failed.

Since you keep on using this erroneous value, all bets are off.

You need to check for errors, and if that happens print the value of `errno` to find out what have gone wrong:

```
void* ptr = shmat(shmid, nullptr, 0);
if (ptr == (void*) -1)
{
    std::cout << "Error getting shared memory: " << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Do something similar for `shmget`.

Now it's also easy to understand the `0xffffffffffffffff` value. It's the two's complement hexadecimal notation for `-1`, and it's passed to the first thread that is created.